# Android Alert Dialog black bar on top and bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have the problem that always displays the frame of dialog on my alert dialog.
I don't want to have a black bar on top and bottom.

Can you help me???

```
private void popupDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Quiz1.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_main, null);
    builder.setView(dialogview);
    closeBtn = (ImageButton) dialogview.findViewById(R.id.Rahmen);

    final AlertDialog popupDia =builder.create();
    popupDia.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    popupDia.setCancelable(true);

    popupDia.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            popupDia.dismiss();
        }
    });

    closeBtn .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupDia.dismiss();
        }
    });
    popupDia.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want a black bar, just change the theme of your app from manifest, use light theme  instead of dark, hope it is what you want, to change color of dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but I have found the answer here can you see it.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_main, null);
    ImageButton close = (ImageButton) dialogview.findViewById(R.id.Rahmen);
    final AlertDialog popupDia =builder.create();
    popupDia.setView(dialogview, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    popupDia.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    popupDia.setCancelable(true);
    popupDia.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            popupDia.dismiss();
        }
    });
    close .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupDia.dismiss();
        }
    });
    popupDia.show();
```

the setView must be seted after the buildig, thats it